# Unable to run query with group by

Tags: sql, group-by

I was trying to execute the following command:

```
SELECT name,sum(mark) 
FROM students 
group by name order by mark
```

but I get the error.

> Column "students.mark" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I am unable to understand the error.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this

`SELECT name,sum(mark) FROM students group by name order by sum(mark)`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Move the `SUM` aggregate to `Order by`

```
SELECT name,sum(mark) FROM students group by name order by sum(mark)
```

or use Alias name

```
SELECT name,sum(mark) as Mark FROM students group by name order by mark
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you,

```
SELECT name,sum(mark) FROM students group by name order by sum(mark)
```

You need to specify `sum` aggregate in orderby